# Android App add geofences and receive intents in same service

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm trying to construct a geofencing app, but it seems to only register geofences when the main activity started, and the intent service stops receiving them when the app is closed. So, I moved the add geofence logic into the intent service (along with the intent handling code) and make sure that service gets started, but now the service doesn't get receive any intents at all!

Service definition

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status>
```

Everything in the service (google api client built and connected) is done in `onCreate`,   with both the intent handlers and the geofence registration stuff `onConnected` registers geofences, etc. Basically, I've tried to implement heavily borrowed geofencing sample code (from the docs) in the same service intended to handle those intents.

All the main activity does is starts the service and draws things related to the geofence notifications received in the service.

If you need more info, just let me know.

**edit**

Ok so it seems like we need more information -- an outline of the service:

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

    protected static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    private boolean mGeofencesAdded;
    private PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        populateGeofenceList();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        // handle the intent, send a notification
    }


    private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
        // sends a notification
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this);
    }

    // straight out of the example
    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest()
    {
        ...
    }


    // from a branch of the example that reuses the pending intent
    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent()
    {
        if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null)
        {
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }

    public void populateGeofenceList() {
        for (thing place : listofplaces) {
            mGeofenceList.add(...)
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    public void onResult(Status status)
    {
        // were fences added? usually yes
    }
}
```

My research has been frustrating -- I see people claiming to be able to do something like this from a broadcast receiver (see first comment) but not from a service?

I have a pretty mangled manifest.xml from all the revisions I've been working through:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"
             android:exported="true"
             android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.aol.android.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    ...

</application>
```

Neither adding the `intent-filter` nor the `android:exported="true"` to the service definition helped at all.

Comment: I'm not an android dev*

Comment: Maybe this question can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090674/android-geofencing-no-coming-intents?rq=1

Comment: @TychoTheTaco thanks for the response but it doesnt seem to have any effect -- added "exported", rebuilt and restarted the app + service, still nothing. More infuriating, no debug output to suggest why it may not be working!

Comment: How you make sure that your service is restarting after app is closed ?

Comment: I close the app and then shut down the service in the device settings menu, then restart the app and see all the debug logs from service start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, don't use the [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for this.  Its sole purpose is to get a single intent, run it in a background thread, then stops itself.  What you are looking for is a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), as this will stick around for a while (until the OS starts running low on resources).

**Second**, once you move your code to a Service, do the following:

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsService extends Service implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {
    //Whatever you need to declare
    ....
    GeofencingRequest mRequest;

    //This is only called once per instance of a Service, so use this to instantiate class variables
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    //Every time you call context.startService(Intent intent) after the service is created, 
    //this function gets called with the intent you have given it. You can use this to modify or change the geofence api,
    //passing GeofencingRequests in intents by calling intent.putExtra(...) before sending the intent, and retrieving it here.
    //I just assume you are passing GeofencingRequest objects, since they are pacelable.
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
        mRequest = intent.getParcelableExtra("request"); //Or whatever the key is for your request.
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                mRequest,
                getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            mRequest,
            getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this);
    }

    // from a branch of the example that reuses the pending intent
    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent()
    {
        if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null)
        {
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;
        }

        mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, GoogleGeofenceReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }

    //The rest of your code
    ....
}
```

Keep in mind that Android will kill your service when it runs low on resources, without much if any warning.  I strongly suggest you look into [starting in the foreground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) if you need this service to run at a higher priority.

**Third**, now that we have the service setup, you may have noticed the `getGeofencePendingIntent()` function now uses a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) instead of the service it is running in.  Here is how you set that up:

```
public class GoogleGeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        ...
        //Do whatever you did in your Service handleIntent function here.
    }
}
```

**Fourth**, you'll need to modify your Manifest to let the app know that this BroadcastReceiver should be used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsService"
             android:exported="true"
             android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.aol.android.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name=".GoogleGeofenceReceiver"/>

    ...

</application>
```

I'm not sure why you are using the export and enabled flags, but they don't need to be declared, because enabled is set by default, and exported is defaulted "true" if you have an intent-filter.

I would suggest you read up on Activity, Service, and BroadcastReceiver life cycles, as understanding that would greatly benefit you with this project and give you a better understanding of the pain of Android in general.

Comment: This is perfect. The bit that absolutely fixes everything is using the receiver for a pending intent. 1) Why does it need to be a broadcast receiver? 2) The broadcast receiver seems to have `onReceive` called quite long after the location has changed -- is there a fundamental difference between registering the pending intent for the receiver (=lag) and an activity (=no lag)?

Comment: one additional thing - after a few `onReceive`, the broadcast receiver stops working  (does not receive any more intents). I'm looking into it; it may just be an *extreme* case of this lag problem.

Comment: 1) It doesn't have to be a BroadcastReceiver, but it is the more appropriate class to use, since the onReceive method is called on the main thread, where the onHandleIntent method is run in a background thread.  This is very important if you are trying to manipulate the UI.  2) The reason for the long delay is that Google geofence API seems to use network locations to verify whether the device has entered/exited the geofence, and there is a high degree of inaccuracy with network locations. From the last time I tested, it took an extra 50m after I exited a geofence for it to register.